# How can I Hide a TextField of Laravel Form?

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, textfield

I want a text field to be hidden for default for a TextField in Laravel Form and then Unhide it when I click a checkbox..

How can I do that ?

Tried adding style properties to the TextField :

```
{{Form::text('Password', $user->email, array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'visible = false;'))}}
```

didn't work..

Comment: `'visible = false;'` not really valid css you got there. You're looking for `visibility: hidden;` That still doesn't solve the problem though. Javascript comes to mind here.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, I'd imagine there's a class or attribute you can use, just like you can for tabs. data-toggle possibly?

Answer (score 3):

```
{{Form::text('Password', $user->email, array('class' => 'form-control hidden'))}}
```

and on javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#checkbox').change(function (){
        $('.form-control.hidden').removeclass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is jQuery, not javascript per se. But close enough!

Comment: Well it's library. It's like saying that PHP is not PHP per se, it's C, and you wouldn't be wrong with either statements.

Comment: @user3791372 he's using bootstrap classes so i thought he might be using jquery as well

Comment: @xhulio Yep, not criticising, just pointing it out for newbies who don't know the difference between javascript / jQuery!

Comment: . @Andrew Rethink your statement. PHP is nothing like C!

Comment: @user3791372 Well of course it's not like C, but at it's core it's C. As jQuery, at it's core is Javascript. If we keep going we're gonna end up in some abstract 0s and 1s realm xD

Comment: @Andrew so you're stating jQuery is a programming language?

Comment: @user3791372  "Well it's library." quote, unquote.

Comment: @Andrew PHP isn't a library. Your "argument" is invalid.

Comment: Guys chill. @user3791372 A framework is something that usually forces a certain way of implementing a solution, whereas jQuery is just a tool to make implementing what you want to do easier. jQuery: "The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library". For sure, it's a javascript library